# Grouping Month and day from the Date in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-analysis

I am having a dataframe like this

```
  Date        Temerature
2016-01-01      3
2017-01-01      4
2016-02-01      5
2017-02-01      7
2016-03-01      2
2017-03-01      4
```

Now, I want to get the Average temperature temperature based on Month and day like this

```
 Date      Temperature
Jan 1         3.5
Feb 1         6
Mar 1         3
```

So, I want to make a new data frame like this, How is it possible in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2017-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2017-03-01'],
                   'Temerature': [3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day

df.groupby(['Month', 'Day'])['Temerature'].mean().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %d'), sort=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
             Temerature
Date                   
January 01          3.5
February 01         6.0
March 01            3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date":["2016-01-01","2017-01-01","2016-02-01","2017-02-01","2016-03-01 ","2017-03-01 "],
    "Temerature":[3,4,5,7,2,4]
})
```

Transform data:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], infer_datetime_format=True)
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%B %d')

df = df.groupby(["Date"], sort=False).mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
print(df)  
          Date  Temerature
0   January 01         3.5
1  February 01         6.0
2     March 01         3.0
```